# sets defining ordinary lines

Tags: combinatorics

An ordinary line is a line that goes through exactly 2 points on a plane. It is well known that if we put any  finite number of points on the plane in any configuration whatsoever, then there will be at least 1 ordinary line (excluding the degenerate case of all points on a single line).

Consider an infinite grid consisting of squares of length 1, where at each intersection you can place a point. Let's place 3 points on the grid to form a triangle. Then, if we see any ordinary line let's put another point on the grid as to make that line non-ordinary. There is clearly more than one way to proceed at each point. This is clearly an infinite process. My question is:Beginning with the configuration shown in the picture, regardless of how we choose the new points, is there a place on the grid on which we will never put any point?

My work so far: If we consider an infinite grid where each intersection has been filled in with a point and we remove a single point, no ordinary line results. It would seem, therefore that there must be some initial configuration and method of choosing points such that not all places on the grid get filled in.

[image: initial configuration]

Comment: You'll have to be more precise. This is quite unclear. Of course, if a line goes through two points on a plane, it goes through infinitely many points on that plane--all the points on the line are on the plane. You must have in mind some set of distinguished points. And what makes a line "unordinary"?

Comment: Your initial statement isn’t quite true: if there are more than two points in the configuration, the points must not be collinear.